# How to make a custom CasperJS module with custom parameter?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

**FileUtil.js**:

```
exports.a = function(pre) {
    var module = {}

    module.writeStringToFile = function writeStringToFile() {
        casper.log(pre + " succ");
    };

    return module
}
```

**main.js**:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var FileUtil = require('FileUtil').a('xxx')
FileUtil.writeStringToFile() //xxx succ
```

That works, but what I want is `var FileUtil = require('FileUtil')('xxx')` instead of `require('FileUtil').a('xxx')`.

I tried `exports = function(pre) ...`, but it doesn't works.

So, how to make a custom CasperJS module with custom parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `var FileUtil = require('FileUtil')('xxx')` to be your object then you need to use `module.exports`. It can export a single object, which can even be a function:

```
module.exports = function(pre) {
    var module = {}

    module.writeStringToFile = function writeStringToFile() {
        casper.log(pre + " succ");
    };

    return module
}
```

Of course, it would be a better form to rename the inner `module` variable to something else.

Comment: I am a little bit curious...Why all of the official library of CasperJS (such as `util.js`) use `exports` instead of `module.exports`? What's the different between `exports` and `module.exports`?

Comment: No idea. Perhaps it's personal preference.